# Per my design requirements, does this design hierarchy seem reasonable?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, inheritance, class-design, hierarchy

**Background**

*Construction*

Note that I am using C# here, but it may not be necessary to provide input to my conceptual questions about design. Consider the following design methodology...

I work at a place where we have a number of different versions of a particular product. Recently I was given a design specification for *3* of the versions, wherein the specification states that the 3 versions are identical except that each has a different name. While I was only given a specification for the 3 versions, there are actually more than just 3. I need to begin writing a base-class object per the design specification. For the sake of this question, I will refer to the base class of this product as `ProductObject`.

Additionally, each `ProductObject` contains 16 objects which for the sake of this question I will refer to as `EntryObject`. Each of the 16 `EntryObject`(s) will need slightly different member fields, but are more or less loosely based on the same thing.

*Usage*

The appropriate version of `ProductObject` will be constructed with a string of "double-space" separated bytes, which I will refer to as `SeparatedBytes`. `SeparatedBytes` will always have the same format, a header followed by the string of bytes. No matter how many different versions of `ProductObject`, the incoming `SeparatedBytes` will always be identical except with varying payloads. The payloads are just sensor readings and do not have anything to do with how the data actually looks in terms of format (will always look like a string of bytes separated by a double-space). Here is how `SeparatedBytes` looks:

```
01  EF  AB  02  ...  XX
```

This string of "double-space" separated bytes will be parsed/split and passed on to their respective `EntryObjects`. Each of the 16 `EntryObject`(s) will be constructed as one *32-bit* word worth of the `SeparatedBytes`. So construction of `EntryObject` should look like:

```
EntryObject myEntryObject = new EntryObject("01EFAB02");
```

The first 4 bytes will be the first type of `EntryObject`, the second 4 bytes will be the second type of `EntryObject`, the third 4 bytes will be the third type of `EntryObject`, up until the sixteenth type of `EntryObject`.  This will look something like...

```
EntryObjectType1 type1 = new EntryObjectType1("12345678");
EntryObjectType2 type2 = new EntryObjectType2(the next four bytes);
EntryObjectType3 type3 = new EntryObjectType3(the next four bytes);

.
.
.

EntryObjectType16 type16 = new EntryObjectType16(the final four bytes);
```

**Proposed Design/Inheritance Hierarchy**

I plan on tackling my design in the following manner, in having a namespace consisting of the following:

1. Have a base-class for the `ProductObject`.
2. Construct 3 child-classes for each of the `ProductObject` versions.
3. Have a base-class for the `EntryObject`.
4. Have 16 derived child-classes from the `EntryObject` base class.
5. Have 16 public `EntryObject` members within the `ProductObject` base-class.

**Questions/Concern**

My concern is mainly with #5 here. I am concerned with #5 because I was only given the first 3 versions of `ProductObject` to work with.

*What if, down the road a new version of* `ProductObject` *comes along and the `EntryObject`(s) within, behave differently?* *Will I be able to accomodate such a change properly, given my proposed design hierarchy?*

Comment: How is this hierarchy/design supposed to be used?

Comment: @Euphoric Add it to the question, or answer you in a comment?

Comment: Add it to a question.

Comment: @Euphoric yes sir.

Comment: @Euphoric Thank you for your comment, and see the "usage" section in my edited post!

Comment: No. In general, inheritance is not the right solution once you start talking about more than a handful of inheritors.

Comment: @Telastyn alternative?

Comment: Some sort of composition or using a definition class, but without more info about how these things are going to be used, how much they vary, how much they'll change over time, it's hard to say.

Comment: @Telastyn Read the "usage" section. No matter how many different variants, they will all work exactly as I have described. The differences will take place in EntryObject.The ProductObject(s) are all variants of one common thing, which is a GOOD reason to use inheritance. So based on this, why wouldn't you use inheritance for each of the product variants?

Comment: That isn't super clear. If I understand correctly, all your data is always the same? Some header and then 16 words? Then I would _definitely_ not use inheritance.

Comment: @Telastyn I see what you mean, let me address what you are saying in my post in order to make sure that others do not have the same misunderstanding. Still, I see the need for composition but not until we get down to the EntryObject level. I need more details, as of right now I see a need for inheritance at the ProductObject level.

Comment: No the design does not seem reasonable. As others have already said, they don't know what you are trying to accomplish. The names you are using make it difficult, if not impossible to understand what you are trying to achieve. The names of your classes are every bit as important as your "design" choices. However, I suspect you are trying to use generic names. Unfortunately, if that is what you have tried to do, then your generic example isn't providing enough context to provide meaningful responses. So I recommend using something more concrete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Applying OO at the bottom of the design facilitates future change everywhere**

Unless you have some idea of how `ProductObject` may change designing for all change is nonsense. Nonetheless OO and its principles get us more than half way there in any case. But you must use OO "all the way down" but you have not.

**Define a SeparatedBytes class**

`new EntryObject("01EFAB02");`  should not be receiving a string but a `SeparatedBytes` object, or property, or method call, thereof.

Once you fill out that class with the appropriate properties and functionality you are giving clients an API to work with, not that stupid (a technical term in this case) string. And this means all the string handling that currently is going on in the existing higher-level classes goes away. Thus you have facilitated future change through the entire class hierarchy.

**Define classes "all the way down"**

The sub-parts of `SeparatedBytes` probably should be classes as well. The fact that 4 bytes defines a type is screaming to become a class IMHO. If you have to "break off" a 4-byte piece and pass it to another object, it better have some functionality that client can work with.

**... all the way!**

If there is any "special handling" done at the `byte + double-space` level then maybe there is a class here too. Anything that this *structure* can do for itself that can be encapsulated, expressed in business-speak, or simplified for client use.

---

> My concern is mainly with #5 here. I am concerned with #5 because I was only given the first 3 versions of ProductObject to work with.

Now I think I can address this question.

The `type` of those 4 bytes will be encapsulated in some way within the `SeparatedBytes` structure. This "type definition/declaration"  can be contained in the `EntityObject` class and now we can have something like a `ProductObject.EntityObjectCollection` of `List<EntityObject>` - general/generic objects that expose their "type" through the `SeparatedBytes` structure.

Comment: Thanks but I think making that string of data into its own structure or class is a little over the top.

Comment: By structure I mean a class design, whatever that might be. I don't mean a linked list, tree, etc - the "classical" meaning of a data structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to future proof it to allow for different configurations of `EntryObject`s, one option would be to have the base `ProductObject` class have a generic `EntryObject` collection, like `List<EntryObject>` or another kind depending on your requirements, instead of exactly 16 `EntryObject` members.

Comment: There will only ever be exactly 16 EntryObjects inside of the ProductObject (regardless of the ProductObject variant). Also, my concern is not future proofing against EntryObject changing. My concern listed as #5 is ProductObject changing.

Comment: Read this again, and I see where you were going with this actually. Thank you for your answer.